# Abstracting out a function that I call

Tags: haskell

I have a function, which creates syntax colored output

```
    printKeyword :: AST -> String
    printKeyword a = keywordColor (show a)
```

the function `keywordColor` however should be different for different outputs. For example when generating xml keywordColor might look like this

```
    keywordColor :: String -> String
    keywordColor k = "<keyword>" ++ k ++ "</keyword>"
```

Instead when printing to an ANSI Terminal it should look like this

```
    keywordColor :: String -> String
    keywordColor k = "\ESC[28;2;24;255;128m" ++ k ++ "\ESC[0m"
```

In what way(s) could I write `printKeyword` to abstract out `keywordColor` in a way that I can use the same implementation of `printKeyword` with different outputs? Could I use monads or monadtransformers? If so how would that work?

The implementation of `printKeyword` should be kept as simple as possible, hence I am thinking of monads, so I don't have to "manually" carry around extra arguments to `printKeyword`.

Comment: This is underspecified a bit. What extra arguments are there to `printKeyword` - there's just `AST` right now. Why is a function doing XML serialization called `keywordColor` as well? This is a code smell. This definitely shouldn't be a single function. There are numerous ways in which `printKeyword` could use "external" code, but it doesn't necessarily have to be a monad context. Reader monad specifically is just syntax sugar over parameters, they're functionally equivalent. If you can't code this with regular arguments, monadic contexts won't help.

Comment: To paraphrase Einstein, it should be as simple as possible, but no simpler. That means passing a formatting function. `printKeyword :: (String -> String) -> AST -> String`, with `printKeyword f = f . show`. If you can somehow encode a request for a specifically formatted string in a type, then a type class with `printKeyword :: AST -> a` as a method might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The implementation of `printKeyword` should be kept as simple as possible, hence I am thinking of monads, so I don't have to "manually" carry around extra arguments to `printKeyword`.

Automatically passing around extra arguments to functions is what *typeclasses* do. This is an alternative to Izaak's explicit dictionary passing, and also lets you encode more information into the types. To do this, you must add a type for each output format

```
newtype XML = XML String
newtype ANSI = ANSI String
```

and a typeclass that manages the dictionary passing for you

```
class Formatted a where
  keywordColor :: String -> a
```

and implementations for your types

```
instance Formatted XML where
  keywordColor k = XML $ "<keyword>" ++ k ++ "</keyword>"

instance Formatted ANSI where
  keywordColor k = ANSI $ "\ESC[28;2;24;255;128m" ++ k ++ "\ESC[0m"
```

and finally, implement `printKeyword` as

```
printKeyword :: Formatted a => AST -> a
printKeyword = keywordColor . show
```

You might prefer this if

- You want the type system to make sure that you don't confuse XML and ANSI strings
- You have more than one formatting function, which may make explicit dictionary passing unwieldy. (I've assumed that this is relevant to you because you said "argument**s**".)

Note that the return type polymorphism often forces you to use more type annotations to tell the compiler what you mean. The `TypeApplications` extension can help with this:

```
> :t printKeyword @XML
printKeyword @XML :: AST -> XML
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of abstraction I was looking for. Thank you very much good sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `keywordColor` in to `printKeyword` as a parameter:

```
printKeyword :: (String -> String) -> AST -> String
printKeyword keyWordColor a = keywordColor (show a)

xmlKeywordColor :: String -> String
xmlKeywordColor k = "<keyword>" ++ k ++ "</keyword>"

termKeywordColor :: String -> String
termKeywordColor k = "\ESC[28;2;24;255;128m" ++ k ++ "\ESC[0m"
```